# Python: Reducing the RAM usage in a large file read-store-operate-write program

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, conjunctive-normal-form

I have a python program here that converts a DIMACS cnf format file to PLA format. I am reading the CNF clauses from a file and storing them in a list and then running operations on the list elements.
The Program works fine for smaller file with upto 15,000 lines (clauses) but the system runs out of memory when I try to run the program on larger files. I need to operate on files that have around 90,000 to 120,000 lines. Can someone please suggest some changes to optimize the memory usage? Below is my program:

```
import sys

#Input: CNF file path
#Output: dictionary of params and clauses from cnf file
def readCNFFile(name):
    lines_str = []
    inputs_dict = {}
    clause_list = []
    with open(name, "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            lines_str.append(str(line))
        for current in range(len(lines_str)):
            li=lines_str[current].strip()
            if li.startswith("c"):
                pass
            elif li.startswith("C"):
                pass
            elif li.startswith("p"):
                inputs_dict['params'] = li
            else:
                clause_list.append(li)
        inputs_dict['clauses']=clause_list
        f.close()
    return inputs_dict

#Input: inputs_dict["clauses"]
#Output: list of clauses split into integers
def getClauses(clause_list):
    for current in range(len(clause_list)):
        temp = clause_list[current].split()
        clause_list[current] = temp
    for current in range(len(clause_list)):
        nums = [int(n) for n in clause_list[current]]
        clause_list[current]= nums
    return clause_list

#Input: inputs_dict["params"]
#Output: number of inputs in PLA
def getNumInputs(param_list):
    param = param_list.split()
    num_inputs = int(param[2])
    return num_inputs

#Input: inputs_dict["params"]
#Output: number of products in PLA
def getNumProducts(param_list):
    param = param_list.split()
    num_prod = int(param[3])
    return num_prod

#Inputs: 1. list of clauses split into integers
#        2. number of inputs in PLA
#Output: list of products for PLA file    
def getPLAlist(clause_list, num_inputs):
    s = "-"
    temp_list_total=[]
    for current in range(len(clause_list)):
        temp_list = []
        for index in range(1,(num_inputs+1)):
            temp_list.append("-")
        for index in range(len(clause_list[current])):
            for i in range(1,(num_inputs+1)):
                if(abs(clause_list[current][index])==i):
                    if(clause_list[current][index]<0):
                        temp_list[i-1]="1"
                    else:
                        temp_list[i-1]="0"
        temp_list_total.append(temp_list)
    return temp_list_total 

#Inputs: 1. input CNF file path
#        2. list of products for PLA file
#        3. number of inputs in PLA
#        4. number of products in PLA
#Output: print PLA file
def printPLAfile(inputFile, PLA_list, num_inputs, num_prod):
    outputfile = inputFile.split(".")[0] + "_pla2.pla"
    with open(outputfile, "w" ) as file_out:
        file_out.write(".i ")
        file_out.write(str(num_inputs))
        file_out.write("\n.o 1")
        file_out.write("\n.p ")
        file_out.write(str(num_prod))
        file_out.write("\n")
        for current in range(len(PLA_list)):
            for index in range(len(PLA_list[current])):
                file_out.write(PLA_list[current][index],)
            file_out.write(" 1 \n")
        file_out.write(".e")

#Get .pla file from .cnf 
#input: CNF File path
def convert_CNF_2_PLA(name):
    inputs = readCNFFile(name)
    clause_list = getClauses(inputs['clauses'])
    num_vars = getNumInputs(inputs['params'])
    num_clause = getNumProducts(inputs['params'])
    PLA_list = getPLAlist(clause_list, num_vars)
    printPLAfile(name, PLA_list, num_vars, num_clause)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = sys.argv[1]
    convert_CNF_2_PLA(name)
```

Comment: Its really hard to tell from your code, but do you really need to read all the lines into memory?  Is there a dependency between lines?  Or could you not use an iterator to read lines as you go?  Even if that means reading the file once for clauses and again for the other stuff?  Also, if the the actual data is not too variable, you could look into \__slots\__ based classes. Or named tuples. Dicts are great but fairly mem hungry.

Comment: As I check the code, the bottleneck function is the function getPLAlist()
Let me explain the problem and my code:
Suppose I have a clause in each line:
eg. 2 -4 0 in a cnf of 7 inputs
I need to print out 0 in 2nd position and 1 in 4th position and the rest of the 5 positions as "-0-1---" in the PLA file for that line
So I'm creating a list with string "-------" in temp_list
And then replacing the 2nd and then 4th positions with 0 and 1 and then I append the temp_list to the list of PLA lines i.e. temp_list_total.
Any suggestions by which I can improve on this method will be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, but none of this tells me that you need to return the whole list at once.  That's what @Robin Davis is saying as well.  I once had a batch to convert database exports that would blow up on 500k+ tables (code ran table by table and would suck up 3-4 gb before crashing).  Nothing fixed it until I realized *row n* was not dependent on the rows before or after and started to use **yield**.  Speed stayed the same, ram went back down to <100mb levels.  Anything else you throw at this problem is a waste of time, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One word: generators. The basic idea here is that each function only does the amount of work needed to get the next line, and no more. This keeps the memory footprint small. There's definitely more optimization that could be done here, but I don't understand the problem well enough, or have any test data to work with. This is utterly untested but it might work!

```
import sys

def readCNFParams(name):
    with open(name, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            li=line.strip()
            if li[0] == "p":
                return li

def readCNFClauses(name):
    with open(name, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            li=line.strip()
            if li[0] in ("c", "C", "p")
                continue
            else:
                yield li

#Input: inputs_dict["clauses"]
#Output: list of clauses split into integers
def getClauses(clause_list):
    clause_list = (c.split() for c in clause_list)
    return ([int(n) for n in c] for c in clause_list)

#Input: inputs_dict["params"]
#Output: number of inputs in PLA
def getNumInputs(param_list):
    param = param_list.split()
    num_inputs = int(param[2])
    return num_inputs

#Input: inputs_dict["params"]
#Output: number of products in PLA
def getNumProducts(param_list):
    param = param_list.split()
    num_prod = int(param[3])
    return num_prod

#Inputs: 1. list of clauses split into integers
#        2. number of inputs in PLA
#Output: list of products for PLA file    
def getPLAlist(clause_list, num_inputs):
    s = "-"
    for current in clause_list:
        temp_list = []
        for index in range(1,(num_inputs+1)):
            temp_list.append("-")
        for index in range(len(current)):
            for i in range(1,(num_inputs+1)):
                if(abs(current[index])==i):
                    if(current[index]<0):
                        temp_list[i-1]="1"
                    else:
                        temp_list[i-1]="0"
        yield temp_list

#Inputs: 1. input CNF file path
#        2. list of products for PLA file
#        3. number of inputs in PLA
#        4. number of products in PLA
#Output: print PLA file
def printPLAfile(inputFile, PLA_list, num_inputs, num_prod):
    outputfile = inputFile.split(".")[0] + "_pla2.pla"
    with open(outputfile, "w" ) as file_out:
        file_out.write(".i ")
        file_out.write(str(num_inputs))
        file_out.write("\n.o 1")
        file_out.write("\n.p ")
        file_out.write(str(num_prod))
        file_out.write("\n")
        for current in PLA_list:
            for index in range(len(current)):
                file_out.write(current[index],)
            file_out.write(" 1 \n")
        file_out.write(".e")

#Get .pla file from .cnf 
#input: CNF File path
def convert_CNF_2_PLA(name):
    clauses = readCNFClauses(name)
    clause_list = getClauses(clauses)
    params = readCNFParams(name)
    num_vars = getNumInputs(params)
    num_clause = getNumProducts(inputs['params'])
    PLA_list = getPLAlist(clause_list, num_vars)
    printPLAfile(name, PLA_list, num_vars, num_clause)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = sys.argv[1]
    convert_CNF_2_PLA(name)
```

Comment: When I checked the code, I found the bottleneck to be getPLAlist() Let me explain the problem and my code: Suppose I have a clause in each line: eg. 2 -4 10 0 in a cnf of 15 inputs I need to print out 0 in 2nd position and 1 in 4th position and the "-" rest of the positions as "-0-1-----0-----" in the PLA file for that line So I'm creating a list with string "---------------" in temp_list And then replacing the 2nd, 4th n 10th positions with 0, 1, 0 and then I append the temp_list to the list of PLA lines i.e. temp_list_total. Any suggestions by which I can improve on this will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that is the memory bottle neck. The problem is reading in the entire file, and in fact making multiple copies of it in memory. To use less memory, read just one clause from the file, and generate the pla for it, and repeat.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try this out.